# Error with entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I've spent quiet some time building my Domain Model (using EF CTP5 Code First), and now I thought I'd through some test data and see if everything works. Unfortunately, it seems like my application is loaded with bugs that do not get caught except during runtime because everything compiles perfectly. Anyway, I keep getting the following error:

> An error occurred while saving
>   entities that do not expose foreign
>   key properties for their
>   relationships.

And Here's the inner exception:

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with
>   the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"Item_ItemStatus\". The conflict
>   occurred in database \"CFSharwe\",
>   table \"dbo.ItemStatus\", column
>   'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."

I have no idea why this is happening. I suspected this might be caused by my initializer class in which I'm loading all the static content of the database inside the Seed() method. So I commented the part where I'm adding the ItemStatuses, and I still got the same error. Moreover, I should've gotten this on compile time, not during runtime, no?

Below is the ItemStatus class and part of my test data:

```
public class ItemStatus
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
 public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

//Test data inside the Index() method of the ItemsController
var item2 = new Item
  {
   Title = "iPhone 4",
   Description = "Lorem Ipsum is simply",
   StartingPrice = 400f,
   User = user2,
   Status = 1,
   EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
   StartDate = DateTime.Now,
   BidIncrement = 3f,
   Bids = new List<Bid>(),
   Comments = new List<Comment>(),
   //ItemStatus = _itemsService.GetItemStatusById(1),    
   ViewingUsers = new List<User>(),
   WatchingUsers = new List<User>(),
   Tags = new List<Tag>()
  };
  //here's where I save the data to the database
  var category = _categoryService.GetChildByName(categoryName);
  category.Items.Add(item2);
  _categoryService.Save();
```

**UPDATE:** (requested by Slauma)

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float StartingPrice { get; set; }
    public float? BidIncrement { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Status")]
    public virtual ItemStatus ItemStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual Address PickupAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ChildCategory Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> WatchingUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> ViewingUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    //public virtual ItemRating Rating { get; set; }

    public bool IsValidBidAmount(int amount)
    {
        if (amount <= this.Bids.Max(a => a.Amount))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public bool IsClosed()
    {
        if (this.ItemStatus.Id.Equals(3))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsPending()
    {
        if (ItemStatus.Id.Equals(2))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsPublished()
    {
        if (ItemStatus.Equals(1))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int WinnerId()
    {
        if(IsClosed())
        {
            User highestBidder = null;
            foreach (Bid b in Bids)
            {
                if (b.Amount.Equals(HighestBid()))
                    highestBidder = b.User;
            }
            if (highestBidder != null) return highestBidder.Id;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public float HighestBid()
    {
        return Bids.Max(u => u.Amount);
    }

    public string MainImageLink()
    {
        var mainImage = Images.Single(i => i.Rank.Equals(0));
        return mainImage.Path;
    }

    public string FirstTag()
    {
        return Tags.First().Title;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IDatabaseFactory _databaseFactory;
    private DbContext _context;
    public UnitOfWork(IDatabaseFactory dbFactory)
    {
        _databaseFactory = dbFactory;
    }

    protected DbContext DataContext
    {
        get
        {
            return _context ?? (_context = _databaseFactory.GetDbContext());
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class EfDatabaseFactory : IDisposable, IDatabaseFactory
{
    private SharweEntities _dbContext;


    public DbContext GetDbContext()
    {
        return _dbContext ?? (_dbContext = new SharweEntities());
    }

    public System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext GetObjectContext()
    {
        return _dbContext.ObjectContext;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_dbContext != null)
            _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on the matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where/how are you managing your DBContext?

Comment: You are showing a lot of code but nothing that's relevant to your problem. Helpful would be the `Item` class in addition to `ItemStatus` and the code where you create Item and ItemStatus, add it to the DbContext and call SaveChanges. Also if you placed attributes on the model class properties or if you customized the model with Fluent API and how. And remove this Lore ipsum and image stuff...

Comment: @Derek Beattie: I am using a UnitOfWork to manage the DbConext. In the above snippet (which I've edited), I call the Save() method on the categoryService which calls the unitOfWork.Commit() which in turn calls context.SaveChanges()

Comment: @Slauma: I've updated my post and added the code I already had. Do you think the problem is with the `Status` property which I've marked as a FK using DataAnnotations?

Comment: Is _itemService using a different DBContext than _categoryService?

Comment: @Derek Beattie: Hmmm... I haven't thought about that, they both take an instance of IUnitOfWork in their constructor. I'll post the implementation of my UnitOfWork class, which I intend to expand on by the way...

Comment: @Kassem: Your FK attribute says, `int Status` is the FK to the `ItemStatus` table. Since it's not nullable, it's a required relationship. You set `Status=1` before you save `Item2`. So, question: Is there an `ItemStatus` row in the database with `Id = 1`?

Comment: @Slauma: Theoretically, there should be. I've already added the content of the ItemStatus table inside the Seed() method.

Comment: @Slauma: Yup, I've just checked the database. There are three records in the ItemStatus table (the ones I'm adding through the Seed() method).

Comment: @Kassem: Is this line in your code above `//ItemStatus = _itemsService.GetItemStatusById(1),` really commented out in the code you are testing with?

Comment: @Slauma: Yes it is commented out. When I uncomment it, I get this error: `The EntitySet 'ItemStatus' is not defined in the EntityContainer 'CodeFirstContainer'.`

Comment: @Slauma: Ah you were actually right! The problem is with the Status property. I am actually adding two items in my test data, I've just found out that I forgot to set `Status = 1` on the first item. But now that I got past this particular bug, a bunch of others have arisen! On a side note, Derek got me thinking about the UnitOfWork, should I inject it into the constructor of every service class (in my service layer) or into my controller's constructor?

Comment: @Slauma: Could you please copy the comment I marked as a "great comment" and post it as an answer so I could accept it as the right answer? Thanks a lot, you've been very helpful :)

Comment: @Kassem: Accept Ladislav's answer below, he had the same idea. Regarding your last question: I don't know what your services are exactly doing, but they seem to work a bit like repositories (you pull objects out of the services while the UnitOfWork is still open, mix the objects from different services somehow together and save in one of the services). If you work this way then yes, you must inject the same UnitOfWork/DbContext into all services you are working with and not a new instance into every service. Otherwise you will experience the problems you're describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error says that you don't have `ItemStatus` record with Id = 1 in your database.

Comment: I am having same kind of issue Plz check that.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085329/tryupdatemodel-error