# TryUpdateModel Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

First time I can add Allergies into my DB without a problem is As below screen.

[image]

But when I try to add 2nd record (after save the first record) then it gives below mentioned run time exception (is as below screen).

[image]

**Run time Exception**

[image]

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

**Stack Trace (this is for when I try to add 2nd record for medical table.But it is same for Allergies Table also)**

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Medicati__3214EC0768A0EA12'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Medications'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditMedicalInfo(string providerKey, string ownerKey, string petKey)
{
    var pet = Repository.GetPet(ownerKey, petKey);
    if (TryUpdateModel(pet))
    {
        Repository.Save();
    }
    var url = Url.AbsoluteRouteUrl("PetDetail", new { controller = "customers", action = "detail", providerKey = providerKey, ownerKey = ownerKey, petKey = petKey }) + "#medical";
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

**Pet Model**

```
public class Pet {
        public Pet() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); Created = DateTime.Now; }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50), Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Birth Date"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(PetType)), UIHint("EnumerationList")]
        [Required]
        public int Type { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid BreedId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Breed"), ForeignKey("BreedId")]
        public virtual Breed Breed { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(Gender)), UIHint("EnumerationList")]
        [Required]
        public int? Gender { get; set; }

        public double Weight { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "License #")]
        public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Microchip #")]
        public string MicrochipNumber { get; set; }

        public int? AgeValue { get { return (BirthDate.HasValue) ? (int)(DateTime.Today - BirthDate.Value).TotalDays : default(int?); } }
        public string Age { get { return (BirthDate.HasValue) ? BirthDate.Value.ToAge() : "Unknown"; } }

        public virtual ICollection<PetPhoto> Photos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MedicalRecordOrder> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PetDocument> Documents { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PetNote> Notes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PetProvider> Providers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PetService> PetServices { get; set; }
        public Guid? Avatar { get; set; }
        public virtual MedicalRecord Medical { get; set; }
        public virtual BehavioralRecord Behavioral { get; set; }
        public virtual DietRecord Diet { get; set; }
        public Guid? EmergencyVeterinarianId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("EmergencyVeterinarianId")]
        public virtual Provider EmergencyVeterinarian { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PetContact> Contacts { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(ProfileCreatorType))]
        public int ProfileCreator { get; set; }

        [EnumDataType(typeof(PetClassification)), UIHint("EnumerationList")]
        public int Classification { get; set; }

        [UIHint("InsuranceCarrier")]
        public virtual string InsuranceCarrier { get; set; }

        // Non persisted extensions
        /// <summary>
        /// Non Persisted
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public List<AppointmentInfo> AppointmentInfos { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Non Persisted
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public List<AppointmentInfo> SiblingAppointmentInfos { get; set; }

        public IList<ReservationRequest> ReservationRequests { get; set; }

        [UIHint("QuickList")]
        public virtual ICollection<SpecialInstruction> SpecialInstructions { get; set; }

        public virtual PetSitterRestrictionPermission PetSitterRestrictionPermission { get; set; }
        public virtual PetSitterBehavior PetSitterBehavior { get; set; }
        public virtual PetSitterCleaningRecord PetSitterCleaningRecord { get; set; }
        public virtual PetSitterNote PetSitterNote { get; set; }


    }
```

**Allergy Model**

```
public class Allergy {
        public Allergy() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Treatment { get; set; }
    }
```

How could I avoid above error when I try to add 2nd record ?

Comment: Why are you setting the GUID in the model, instead of using `[Key]` and allowing the database to set the GUID?  I'm not sure that that would cause this issue, I'm really not seeing anything specific in your code.

Comment: @Michael_B Nope. Guid will not auto generated by the DB.We have to set it inside the model.You could generate automatic int identity key but not for GUID.So That is not the cause here.All our models are like this.But no problems for other places.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the `Guid.NewGuid()` created is not a duplicate key?  The code used to insert a new Allergy does not appear to be included in your question.  Could you add that?